# How can I administer IIS 6 from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, iis-6

I'd like to administer my IIS 6 servers from my Windows 7 (RTM) laptop, but the IIS 6 manager won't install.  How can I manage my IIS 6 servers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the [Remote Server Admin Tools (RSAT) for Windows 7](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en).

Comment: Ah ha! I knew I hadn't installed something yet... +1 and thanks for the link.

Comment: ... doh, the link in that article is ker-busted.

Comment: Sorry. Found 'em: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7d2f6ad7-656b-4313-a005-4e344e43997d&displaylang=en

Comment: Hope it helps!  It'll add all the relevant snap-ins under the Administrative Tools menu, which should include IIS.

Comment: A note about the Remote Server Admin Tools (RSAT) for Windows 7.  Once you install them you will have to enable them in the Add/Remove Windows feature under Programs.  They will not automatically show up after installation.  Keep that in mind as I installed them twice because they didn't show up afte rinstallation.

Answer (score 0):

The version linked in the other answer doesn't work with the RC. I (finally) found a working link to the RC version of RSAT since all of the links at Microsoft's site have been removed.

I hope this saves someone else some time.

[Remote Server Admin Tools (RSAT) for Windows 7 RC](http://cid-82e525f580e33098.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/Windows6.1-KB958830-x86.msu)